# PHP/MySQL verifying the result of a query?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got this code that should delete a row, containing a certain number from the database.

```
if ( isset($_POST['textfield_numtodelete']) )
{

$numToDel = $_POST['textfield_numtodelete'];

$resdel = mysqli_query( $con,"DELETE FROM pncall_numbers WHERE Number = '$numToDel'");

if ( $resdel ) { echo ("<center>".$numToDel." deleted successfully.</center>"); } else { echo("<center>".$numToDel." not found in database.</center>"); }

}
```

If successful, it should output "deleted successfully", else "not found in database". Yet $resdel always is true, even if I try to delete a number that's not there...

Thanks!

Comment: Please note that this is vulnerable to SQL injections. Furthermore, quoting a number isn't standard SQL.

Comment: As a side note you really need to escape the $numToDel parameter: $mysqli->real_escape_string($numToDel)

Comment: For $numToDel, you can also use intval(). That converts the string to an integer.

Comment: Also note that the center tag is deprecated.

Comment: Actually, he really should be using prepared statement.

Answer (score 3):

`true` is returned because the query was successfully executed, even if no rows were deleted. Try [mysqli->affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) after deletion

Comment: Roger, if this answer helped you then please select this as "Answer".